# Passing variables between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread that processes updates and then calls a method on the main `Form` to display the result.

While this works to some extent the synchronization means that if updates come in too quickly then the wrong (previous) data is displayed.

I have created an object that is passed in with the `ref` keyword, made things `volatile`, etc. but I can still not get synchronized data.

```
public class SharedData
{
    public String notifyTime;
    public String notifyType;
    public String notifyData;
}

public void StartNotificationOutputWorkerThread()
{
        notificationOutputWorker = new NotificationOutputWorker(
                                                    ref oddsUpdates,
                                                    ref willPayUpdates,
                                                    ref eventDataUpdates,
                                                    ref resultDataUpdates,
                                                    ref runnerDataUpdates,
                                                    ref meetingDataUpdates,
                                                    ref optionUpdates,
                                                    ref selectionUpdates,
                                                    ref notifyShare,
                                                    this,
                                                    Context
                                                   );
        notificationOutputWorkerThread = new Thread(notificationOutputWorker.DoWork);
        notificationOutputWorkerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        notificationOutputWorkerThread.IsBackground = true;
        notificationOutputWorkerThread.Start();
}

public void UpdateNotifications()
{
        Application.DoEvents();
        AddDataItem(LV_GPS, new List<String> 
                              { 
                                notifyShare.notifyTime, 
                                notifyShare.notifyType, 
                                notifyShare.notifyData 
                              });
}

// Worker Thread
public NotificationOutputWorker(
                                 ref UpdateRace aOddsUpdate,
                                 ref UpdateRace aWillPayUpdates,
                                 ref UpdateRace aEventDataUpdates,
                                 ref UpdateRace aResultDataUpdates,
                                 ref UpdateRace aRunnerDataUpdates,
                                 ref UpdateRace aMeetingDataUpdates,
                                 ref UpdateSportsOption aOptionUpdates,
                                 ref UpdateSportsOption aSelectionUpdates,
                                 ref SharedData aNotifyShare,
                                 Form1 _form,
                                 SynchronizationContext _context
                                 )
{
    oddsUpdate         = aOddsUpdate;
    willPayUpdates     = aWillPayUpdates;
    eventDataUpdates   = aEventDataUpdates;
    resultDataUpdates  = aResultDataUpdates;
    runnerDataUpdates = aRunnerDataUpdates;
    meetingDataUpdates = aMeetingDataUpdates;
    optionUpdates      = aOptionUpdates;
    selectionUpdates   = aSelectionUpdates;

    notifyShare = aNotifyShare;

    form = _form;
    this.context = _context;
}

private void UpdateOptions()
{
    while (optionUpdates.syncUpdates.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            String optionNumber = null;
            lock (_locker)
            {
                optionNumber = (String)optionUpdates.syncUpdates.Dequeue();
                optionUpdates.hashes.Remove(optionNumber);
            }
            OutputNotification(GetTime(), "Option", optionNumber);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}

public void OutputNotification(String _time, String _type, String _data)
{
    lock (_locker)
    {
        notifyShare.notifyTime = _time;
        notifyShare.notifyType = _type;
        notifyShare.notifyData = _data;
    }

    this.Context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(notificationUpdate), null);
}

public void notificationUpdate(object state)
{
    form.UpdateNotifications();
    form.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Passing a bunch of variables by reference, and then just copying the value once and never touching the variables passed by reference again is just pointless.  Your code would be unchanged if you just didn't pass those variables by reference.   You also shouldn't be calling `DoEvents`.  Do your work asynchronously, rather than blocking the UI thread.  It's also pointless to lock around access to a given object from one thread but not from another.  You've accomplished nothing by doing so.

Comment: Apart from your need to point out some of the code as "pointless", did you actually have a valid suggestion as to how I can ensure that the variables are updated when I access them?

Comment: Yes, it's right there in that comment.  I've explained to you why each of the various mechanisms that you *think* are solving the problem that you're trying to solve are actually doing nothing at all.  You could remove them, as they aren't doing anything useful, or you could fix them, so they function properly.

Comment: @BrianHewitson - Please never ever call `Application.DoEvents()` - it's only in the framework for backward compatibility with VB6. It's use in modern apps will likely eventually cause you re-entrancy errors that are a nightmare to debug and difficult to then refactor a clean solution. You should use one of many up-to-date options.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks for that. I only added this particular call as I was trying anything at that stage. As you can see by my final comment, I did not have the problem corrected identified.

Comment: Put all your synchronization data into an immutable struct and only post results that are copies of the original data. This way you only need to block the thread once during the copying and what you do with the resutls afterward is not affected by the processing thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are not locking your code properly; you're making a lock while updating the variables and then releasing it when starting to execute the next function, and since the variable `notifyShare` is shared your code is not thread-safe. I suggest changing your code to the following :

```
private void UpdateOptions()
{
     while (optionUpdates.syncUpdates.Count > 0)
     {
         try
         {
             String optionNumber = null;
             lock (_locker)
             {
                 optionNumber = (String)optionUpdates.syncUpdates.Dequeue();
                 optionUpdates.hashes.Remove(optionNumber);                 
                 OutputNotification(GetTime(), "Option", optionNumber);
             }          
         }
         catch (Exception ex)  { }
     }
}

public void OutputNotification(String _time, String _type, String _data)
{ 
    notifyShare.notifyTime = _time;
    notifyShare.notifyType = _type;
    notifyShare.notifyData = _data;  
    /* I'm not really sure if this call will be synchronously exected, but if 
     not  then the locking will not be useful and so I prefer to pass the notification 
     details as parameters to the method instead of using a shared object.*/
    this.Context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(notificationUpdate), null);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has  made no difference.

Comment: The problem is that there is not a linear mapping between OutputNotification being triggered and notificationUpdate being triggered. I have stopped using shared data and moved the other call into the locking as you suggested.

Comment: public void OutputNotification(String _time, String _type, String _data)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                notifyShare = new SharedData();
                notifyShare.notifyTime = _time;
                notifyShare.notifyType = _type;
                notifyShare.notifyData = _data;
                this.Context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(notificationUpdate), null);  
            }       
        }

Comment: I am unsure how to make sure that everytime OutputNotification is called it performs notificationUpdate before it process the next data

Comment: I have asked for this question to be deleted as it is not accurate. The problem I am having is not getting the data out but ensuring that the thread calls the function on the main thread every time one piece of data is processed. What is happening when data arrives too fast is that I will get the last value repeated many times as the data is overwritten before being processed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void OutputNotification(String _time, String _type, String _data)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            notifyShare = new SharedData();
            notifyShare.notifyTime = _time;
            notifyShare.notifyType = _type;
            notifyShare.notifyData = _data;
            sharedQueue.Enqueue(notifyShare);
            this.Context.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(notificationUpdate), null);  
        }       
    }

    public void notificationUpdate(object state)
    {
        if (sharedQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            SharedData temp = (SharedData)sharedQueue.Dequeue();
            form.UpdateNotifications(temp);
        }
    }
```